# Triggering a modal with a Chrome extension when some text is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to trigger a modal that I have created when some piece of text is selected in the browser. I have handled the text selection part, but cannot trigger the modal. I tried to do the following:

Here is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="eliaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select an Option</h4>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <p1 class="labelHeadingClass" id="selectedHeadP"></p1>
                <p1 class="labelTextClass" id="selectedTextP"></p1>
                <br/>
                <p1 class="labelHeadingClass" id="translatedHeadP"></p1>
                <p1 class="labelTextClass" id="translatedTextP"></p1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="translateP" >Translate</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="extractText" >Extract Text</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And here is how I call it in my background.js file where the message is handled:

```
$("#eliaModal").modal("show");
```

Nothing happens. I made sure that this code is executed and localized the problem to here. My idea here is that the background.js file tries to find this modal in the webpage which the user is viewing, whereas the modal is on a separate HTML file. I feel like I have to inject this to the webpage that the user is viewing, but I couldn't get a proper way to do that and I am not even sure if that is the right way. I would appreciate if someone can point me the right direction.

Comment: "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },

Comment: The background script runs in a special separate hidden background page, not in the web page or the popup, so it sounds like you're using it incorrectly. To modify a web page you need a *content script*.

Comment: And since it seems that you're using a Bootstrap modal, beside you JS and HTML code you'll also have to inject the CSS and JS dependencies of Bootstrap.

Comment: In my opinion, instead of injecting all that as a content script, you could create a small webpage which contains the modal and inject a `iframe` element into the website to display it. That will keep the context of you modal separate (it won't mess up the website).